# Multithreading synchronization between reading and writing in a channel

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I was hoping to get some feedback on what the recommended design pattern are for this subject.

```
public class Channel {

    private AtomicInteger buffer = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public void read() {
        // This function should keep blocking until there is something to read.

        while (buffer.get() == 0) {
            // Maybe a sleep? (Although NetBeans gives a warning for a sleep in a loop)
        }

        buffer.decrementAndGet();
    }

    public void write() {
        // This function should just write (nothing) to the buffer (by increasing the counter of the imaginary buffer).
        buffer.incrementAndGet();
    }
}
```

Is this safe for use in multithreading? Or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if multiple threads try to read they may each decrement the buffer if one thread was interrupted right before it could decrement and after it passed the while

Instead use a [Semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) which is designed for just this:

```
public class Channel {

    private Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(0);

    public void read() throws InterruptedException {
        // This function should keep blocking until there is something to read.

        sem.acquire();
    }

    public void write() {
        // This function should just write (nothing) to the buffer (by increasing the counter of the imaginary buffer).
        sem.release();
    }
}
```

otherwise you should decrement in a loop:

```
int read;
do{
    while((read = buffer.get())==0){
    //sleep
    }
}while(!buffer.compareAndSet(read, read-1));
```

Comment: Alright, that looks like exactly what I'm in need of. But how should I handle the InterruptedException?

Comment: You should stop the thread; it's a mechanism to aid asynchronous shutdown. Though if you never interrupt the thread then you can ignore it

Comment: @Tim I disagree with ignoring any exception. Usually, you should simply terminate what you're doing. The simplest way is not catching the `InterruptedException`. This spams the whole code with `throws` clauses, but that's Java. Alternatively, wrap it in a `RuntimeException`. If you really don't want to terminate, than call `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` so that it doesn't get lost.